# Python looping [Module]

Tags: python, loops, terminal

I am new at Python programming language. If exactly, it's my first day.
I am making a terminal, which code is visible here: [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/iekYatQY)
I wan't to the code loop from here (/###) to here (###/).

```
/### 
lastcommand = input("C-Gen@H//Vilius #OpDesc: ")
if lastcommand == "info":
    print (info)
elif lastcommand == "list1":
    print (list1)
elif lastcommand == "list2":
    print (list2)
elif lastcommand == "list3":
    print (list3)
elif lastcommand == "session_name":
    print (session_name)
elif lastcommand == "myName":
    print (myName)
elif lastcommand == "currentloc":
    print (currentloc)
elif lastcommand == "currentfold":
    print (currentfold)
elif lastcommand == "filenameloc":
    print (filenameloc)
elif lastcommand == "cpu":
    print (cpu)
else:
    print ("Error: incorrect command (" + lastcommand + ")")
###/
```

Comment: When do you want it to loop? How long?

Comment: From lastcommand input till the print after else statement, forever

Comment: Well, it only says how make a number looping, not the code looping.

Comment: Take care that in python indentation is part of the syntax

Comment: Yeah, it's a little bit bugged on the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to loop forever, you can use `while True` like so:

```
while True:
    lastcommand = input("C-Gen@H//Vilius #OpDesc: ")
    if lastcommand == "info":
        print (info)
    elif lastcommand == "list1":
        print (list1)
    elif lastcommand == "list2":
        print (list2)
    elif lastcommand == "list3":
        print (list3)
    elif lastcommand == "session_name":
        print (session_name)
    elif lastcommand == "myName":
        print (myName)
    elif lastcommand == "currentloc":
        print (currentloc)
    elif lastcommand == "currentfold":
        print (currentfold)
    elif lastcommand == "filenameloc":
        print (filenameloc)
    elif lastcommand == "cpu":
        print (cpu)
    else:
        print ("Error: incorrect command (" + lastcommand + ")")
```

`while` will loop until the provided condition evaluates to `False`. But here you give it `True`, which is never false, so it will loop forever until Python sees a `break` statement somewhere.

However, you can make your code far simpler by using a dictionary. Try this:

```
info_dict = {}
info_dict["info"] = info
info_dict["list1"] = list1
# ... and do that with the rest of it.
while True:
    lastcommand = input("C-Gen@H//Vilius #OpDesc: ")
    try:
        print info_dict[lastcommand]
    except KeyError:
        print ("Error: incorrect command (" + lastcommand + ")")
```

Then you don't have all those terrible `elif`s, and you can directly access the variables using the entered strings.